# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this error while adding **`"com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0"`** this script in my `build.gradle` dependency.

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Apply this in build.gradle(Project: your project name) where tools.build:gradle is present and not in build.gradle(Module: app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

In build.gradle(Module: app) outside dependencies add this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I tried to add this dependency to connect to google analytics and added this to build.gradle(module) but showing the same error

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing problem of connecting firebase to android studio then
goto `Tools` -> `Firebase` -> `Select any option like authenticate using google-sign in`  -> then click add the firebase authenticate -> Dependencies will be added automatically.
This helped me.