# I keep getting the same error in android studio "Error Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services:4.0.1]"

Tags: android, android-studio

I keep getting the same error when i buil the program, I have tried to switch things around, remove and add other stuff but ultimatey I get the same error in the build.gradle of my app, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Apply this in build.gradle(Project: your project name) where tools.build:gradle is present and not in build.gradle(Module: app).

For detailed description visit the link -

[Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232312/could-not-find-method-classpath-for-arguments-com-google-gmsgoogle-services)